Converting a digital (0, +5 volt) signal to (+30, -30 volt) signal using mosfets
I'm trying to convert 0, 5 V signal to +30, -30 V using MOSFETs, the signal is generated by a microcontroller, but I haven't got any idea so far on how to convert it,
The +30 -30 voltages are ready (using lm317 and lm337 regulators) and the problem is with converting from 0 5 (100 Hz) signal to +30 -30 (100 Hz),
***Note: I have a digital signal generated by a microcontroller that provides a square wave (0, 5), and I want to convert it to a digital signal of 30, -30 V.


What is creating the 5V signal and where is it going? I.e. what are the input and output impedances and currents involved?

Do you mean digital signal where just 0V is 30V and 5V is -30V, or analog where example 2.5V on input is 0V on output and so..

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Is it (0-5) or (0, 5)?

My square wave (30, -30) is going to an impedance between 1 ohm to 1k ohm

1 ohm at 30 V is 900 W. You need a power supply which can match this. How precise do you need the +30 and -30 V levels to be? How sharp rise and fall times do you need?

There is no problem with the power supply, the 30 -30 levels need to be relatively precise and sharp, no problem with some voltage drop

LM317 delivering 30 V cannot drive a 1 ohm load without the output voltage dropping rather a lot

Note that the mosfet circuit will drive that impedance, please don't think about those peripherals, the only thing is to build the mosfet circuit that converts the signal, in the case of power supply, I will limit the delivered current finally.

"relatively precise" and "no problem with some voltage drop" are contradictory. As Neil says, your LM317/337 are 29 A short of your 30 A target.

I said I Don't need 900w power, I will limit the delivered current finally, the problem is with converting the signal

No, in fact you stated the exact opposite. That's why questions are asked.

Simple with two opto-couplers:


Thanks a million, so can we use this for +100 -100 volts? I mean to increase or decrease the signal level?

Something like 1n4744?

@user23328818  It would work but you have to change the 4k7 resistors that supplies the zeners to about 22kohm/2W. But  it wouldn’t work at +-30V then, because a too few current would flow through zeners.

OK, so for +5 -5 signal, I should decrease the value of 4k7 resistor? What is the formula for calculations? If I know the formula, I can design a switching circuit to switch between multiple zeners and resistors to achieve this

The current through zener should be about 4mA at least. So for 100V load supply you can calculate the series resistor as: (100V-15V)/4mA=21kohm , so pick the 22K. For 30V supply (30-12)/4mA=4.5kohm , use 4k7…..Note: The current doesn’t have to be precise 4mA, but let´s say 3–10mA for this application. –

Thanks, For 5 volt signal out, what type of zener should i choose? Can this circuit work for signals of 5volt, 10, etc?

For 5-15V don’t use a zener and this resistor at all. Just connect the optocouplers directly to Gnd. The zeners are there just to decrease voltage to mosfets gates (Vgs).

As I got the zener and its supply circuit is for holding the mosfet's gate at a specific voltage level and the input 0 5 volt signal(from mcu) will drive the mosfet to be off or on, right?

Note that some non-overlap must be added to the two opto signals from the MCU to avoid both MOSFETs being on at the same time time during switching otherwise large shoot-through currents will be generated.

10us between. Each pulse? Added by mcu program
